# jQuery attach change event on hidden file inputs

Tags: jquery, file-io

I'm trying to create/custom the default file type inputs so that they look the same across all common browsers. What I'm doing is hiding the default input and showing my custom file type input. Then I trigger the native click event for the hidden input using trigger method. Then I trigger the native change event to get the chosen/selected file name using the change event. Everything works fine. All these I do from the plugin that I created.

But since there can be more than 1(one) file type input, my solution does not work properly. The change event gets attached to the last input only.

Here is my js code:
$.widget("jQuery.jFile", {
    options: {

```
    wrapperClass:'custom-file',
    buttonClass:'custom-file-button',
    hideClass:'hidden',
    inputClass:'custom-file-input',
    disabledClass:'custom-file-disable',

    disabled:false,
    validation:false,

    inputValue:'No file choosen'
},



_init: function(option) {
    var settings    = $.extend({}, this.options, option); 
    var element     = this.element;

    $(element).wrapAll('<span/>').before('<span/>').prev('span').addClass(settings.buttonClass).html('Choose File').next('input').addClass(settings.hideClass).after('<span/>').next('span').addClass(settings.inputClass).text(settings.inputValue).parent().addClass(settings.wrapperClass);

    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox')>-1) $('.'+settings.wrapperClass).addClass('ff');
    //Bind events
    $('.'+settings.buttonClass).bind('click',this.openFileDialog).bind('mouseover',this.fileDialogMouseover).bind('mouseout',this.fileDialogMouseout).bind('keypress, mousedown', this.fileDialogKeypress).next('input').bind('change',this.fileDialogChange);


},

disable: function() {
    this.options.disabled = true;
},

enable: function() {
    this.options.disabled = false;
},

openFileDialog: function(){
    $(this).next('input').trigger('click'); 
},

fileDialogChange: function(){

    file_value=$(this).val();
    file=file_value.split('\\');
    filename=file[file.length-1];
    if(filename.length>32) filename=filename.substring(0, 29) + '...';


    $(this).next('span').text(filename);

},

fileDialogMouseover: function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover').removeClass('active');
},

fileDialogMouseout: function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover').removeClass('active');
},

fileDialogKeypress: function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('hover');
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I have to unbind the click event before binding the same so that the trigger event is called once.

Thanks anyways :)